# XML Read to Array in Autoit

Tags: xml, arrays, autoit

Is there any easy way to open/edit/save XML file? Any function which can open xml file into array? I tried `_FileReadToArray($filepath, $aArray)` but this has wrong codding (I need utf-16, not ansi)

Answer (score 3):

There is also an "official" function named "_SML_ElementsToArry()"

```
;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _XML_ElementsToArry()
; Description:    Return an array of the elements of an XML file
; Parameter(s):  $sXMLFilePath  - String with full path to XML file
; Requirement(s):   AutoIt 3.1.1.53 Beta or better
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns an array. Element[0] contains the
;                                number of elements found, the remaining
;                                array contains the names of the elements
;                  On Failure - returns -1 and sets @error to 1
; Author(s):        JerryD
;
;===============================================================================
Func _XML_ElementsToArry ( $sXMLFilePath )
    Local $i = 1
    Local $aRetAry[1]
    $aRetAry[0] = 0
    Local $xmldoc = ObjCreate( 'Microsoft.XMLDOM' )
    If Not IsObj($xmldoc) Then
        SetError ( 1 )
        Return -1
    EndIf
    $xmldoc.async = False
    $xmldoc.load ( $sXMLFilePath )
    For $x In $xmldoc.documentElement.childNodes
        $aRetAry[0] = $aRetAry[0] + 1
        ReDim $aRetAry[$aRetAry[0]+1]
        $aRetAry[$i] = $x.NodeName
        $i = $i + 1
    Next
    Return $aRetAry
EndFunc
```

Cheers,
Vlu.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763789.aspx) to properly read the XML file:

```
$oXml = ObjCreate('Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0')
If IsObj($oXml) Then
    $oXml.load('C:\Path\to\your\file.xml')
    If $oXml.parseError.errorCode = 0 Then
        ; Do something with the XML object
    Else
        MsgBox(4096, 'Error', 'Error opening XML file: ' & _
                                   $oXml.parseError.reason)
        SetError($oXml.parseError.errorCode)
    EndIf
EndIf
```

You can then use the MSXML API to build up your array.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for reading an XML file and loading it into a dynamically sized 2D array. It requires Eltorro's [_MSXML.au3](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=44418) UDF.

```
; Load _MSXML.au3 UDF found here: 
; https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=44418
#include <_MSXML.au3>

; Set the XML file
$filename = @ScriptDir & "\Test_1.xml"

; Call the function
$array = XMLtoArray($filename)


Func XMLtoArray($XMLfile)

    Local $oXMLDoc
    _MSXML_InitInstance($oXMLDoc)
    If @error Then
        MsgBox(0,"Error","Failed to create instance")
        Exit
    EndIf
    _MSXML_FileOpen($oXMLDoc, $XMLfile)
    If @error Then
        MsgBox(0,"Error",_MSXML_Error())
    Else
        ; File open and ready.

        local $resultArray[0][0]

        ; Create XML OBJECT
        $oRecords = $oXMLDoc.documentElement.childNodes

        ; Create Array with headers in row 0
        $length = $oRecords.item(0).attributes.length
        ReDim $resultArray[1][$length]
        $j = 0
        For $name in $oRecords.item(0).attributes
            $name = $oRecords.item(0).attributes($j).name
            $resultArray[0][$j] = $name
            $j+=1
        Next

        ; Fill array with values
        For $oRecord In $oRecords
            ReDim $resultArray[UBound($resultArray, $UBOUND_ROWS)+1][UBound($resultArray, $UBOUND_COLUMNS)]
            For $j = 0 To UBound($resultArray, $UBOUND_COLUMNS) - 1 Step +1
                $attributeName = $resultArray[0][$j]
                $attributeValue = $oRecord.GetAttribute($attributeName)
                $resultArray[UBound($resultArray)-1][$j] = $attributeValue
            Next
        Next
        Return $resultArray

    EndIf


EndFunc
```

Comment: This produced "Error: The requested action with this object has failed."  I want to be able to add an XML with embedded

Answer (score 0):

there is a XML DOM Wrapper available for AutoIT.

Just have a look at:

http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/19848-xml-dom-wrapper-com/

The Download Links on the first page are broken (Thread is a bit old ;), so try using these below:

http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/19848-xml-dom-wrapper-com/page-38

[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Silvernine0S/FolderMenu3EX/master/Include/*XMLDomWrapper*.au3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Silvernine0S/FolderMenu3EX/master/Include/_XMLDomWrapper_.au3)

I use the lib with AutoIT Version v3.3.8.1 (Seems to be working so far).